# graphics card getting activated during video? A test using a java (Processing) program

Tags: performance, processing, nvidia, video-card

I have an application I was running that I created with Processing where I was drawing a lot of objects to the screen.  Normally the sketch runs at 60 fps and predictably when a lot of stuff is drawn to the screen, it starts to reduce.  I wanted to see what changing Processing's renderer would do, as there is a P3D option when you set the size.  P3D is a '3D graphics renderer that makes use of OpenGL-compatible graphics hardware.'

I noticed that the performance improved when i used this in that I could draw more objects to the screen before framerate dropped, without really having to change anything in the code.  Then i noticed something odd.

I started up the computer the next day and ran the program again and noticed that suddenly the framerate was lower, around 50 fps. There didn't seem to be anything wrong with my computer as it wasn't doing anything else.  Then I thought it probably has something to do with the graphics card.  I opened a youtube video and it seemed to be fine.  Then I ran the sketch again and it went back up to 60fps.

I just want to know what might be going on here hardware wise.  I'm using an NVIDIA GTX970 (i think its OC edition).  It seems to me that watching the video sort of jump started the card and made it perform on the processing sketch properly.  Why didn't the sketch itself make that happen?

as an example:

```
Vector<DrawableObject> objects;
void setup()
{
   size(400,400, P3D); /// here is the thing to change.  P3D is an option  

  objects = new Vector<DrawableObject>();
  for(int i=0;i<400;i++)
  {
    objects.add(new DrawableObject());

  }

}

void draw()
{
  for(int i=0; i<objects.size(); i++)
  { 
     DrawableObject o = objects.get(i);
     o.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of the code you're running?